# Can Anyone Check my Proof that all linear maps $T:U_1\oplus U_2\longrightarrow V_1\oplus V_2$ are of the form below?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $U_1, U_2$, $V_1$ and $V_2$ are vector spaces such that $$\textrm{dim}(U_1)=\textrm{dim}(V_1)=n-k\quad \textrm{and}\quad \textrm{dim}(U_2)=\textrm{dim}(V_2)=k$$ and $\textrm{dim}(U_2)=\textrm{dim}(V_2)=k$. I'm supposed to show that every linear map $$T:U_1\oplus U_2\longrightarrow V_1\oplus V_2$$ has the form $$T=\left(\begin{array}{cc}A&B\\ C&D \end{array}\right),$$ where $A:U_1\longrightarrow V_1$, $B:U_1\longrightarrow V_2$, $C:U_2\longrightarrow V_1$ and $D:U_2\longrightarrow V_2$ are linear maps. Here I'm identifying the linear maps with their matrices.

I tried a proof, can anyone check it?

**Proof:** Let $\{u_1, \ldots, u_n\}$ be a basis for $U_1\oplus U_2$ and $\{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$ be a basis for $V_1\oplus V_2$. Then $$\{u_1, \ldots, u_{n-k}\}\quad \textrm{and}\quad \{u_{n-k+1}, \ldots, u_n\},$$ are basis for $U_1$ and $U_2$, respectively. Also, $$\{v_1, \ldots, v_{n-k}\}\quad \textrm{and}\quad \{v_{n-k+1}, \ldots, v_n\}$$ are basis for $V_1$ and $V_2$, respectively. Suppose, for every $i=1, \ldots, n$, $$Tu_i=\sum_{j=1}^n \beta_{ij} v_j.$$ For $i=1, \ldots, n-k$ define $$Au_i=\sum_{j=1}^{n-k} \beta_{ij} v_j\quad \textrm{and}\quad Bu_i=\sum_{j=n-k+1}^n \beta_{ij} v_j.$$ This defines linear maps $A:U_1\longrightarrow V_1$ and $B:U_1\longrightarrow V_2$. For $i=n-k+1, \ldots, n$ define $$Cu_i=\sum_{j=1}^{n-k} \beta_{ij} u_j\quad \textrm{and}\quad Du_i=\sum_{j=n-k+1}^n \beta_{ij} v_j.$$ This defines linear maps $C:U_2\longrightarrow V_1$ and $D:U_2\longrightarrow V_2$. By construction, $$T=\left(\begin{array}{cc}A&B\\ C&D \end{array}\right).$$

I hope it is ok!

**Context:** This problem arose when I was trying to show that if $G$ is a smooth manifold with group structure and $G\times G\longrightarrow G$, $(a, b)\mapsto ab$, is smooth then $G\longrightarrow G$, $a\mapsto a^{-1}$, is also smooth and hence $G$ is a Lie group. In the original problem I was supposed to show a linear map $T_aM\oplus T_pP\longrightarrow T_bN\oplus T_pP$ was an isomorphism.

Comment: I do not have time for reading your proof. But the statement looks correct to me.